# ARDUINO DC Motor Control over IR Sensor INPUT

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, esp32, motor, voltage-level

I'm working on a school project where I'm building a small convyeor belt using an ARDUINO, DC motor and IR sensor for moving object detection so my color sensor can read color value.

I'm using single mosfet IRFZ44N to control DC motor. I can control DC motor using mosfet normally as turning it ON/OFF using digitalWrite using an arduino.

So, I want to stop convyeyor belt for 500ms when IR sensor detects HIGH and let color sensor read color of object and then let object move ahead normally on belt.
I have written below code but the IR sensor detect object but motor never stops running.

```
#define IR_COLOR 34 

const int MOTORpin = 32;
const long onDuration = 1000;// OFF time for LED
const long offDuration = 1000;// ON time for LED
int MOTORState =HIGH;// initial state of LED


boolean MOTOROnFlag          = true;


long rememberTime=0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(IR_COLOR, INPUT);
  pinMode(MOTORpin,OUTPUT);// define MOTORpin as output
  digitalWrite(MOTORpin,MOTORState);// set initial state
}

void loop() {
  

  int state = digitalRead(IR_COLOR);


 if( state == false )
 {
    if( (millis()- rememberTime) >= onDuration){   
    MOTORState = LOW;
    rememberTime=millis();
    }
 }
 else if(state == true)
 {   
    if( (millis()- rememberTime) >= offDuration){     
    MOTORState =HIGH;// change the state of LED
    rememberTime=millis();// remember Current millis() time
    }
 }
 



 digitalWrite(MOTORpin,MOTORState);// turn the LED ON or OFF

}// loop ends
```

Comment: you have no IR sensor code

Comment: @jsotola IR_COLOR is IR Sensor.

Comment: what is IR_RED then?

Comment: @jsotola It was made for future work but the initial task is not completed of stoping motor pin for 500ms and starting motor again. Motor stops as IR detects object but it remains off as object is still ahead of IR sensor.

Comment: so what will you name the color sensor? ... it seems like you are using confusing names

Comment: insert a layer of separation between the sensor and the motor ... use a `run` flag ... set it at beginning ... sensor clears the flag and starts a timer ... timer expiration sets the flag .... further down in the code, if flag is set, then run motor

Comment: @jsotola I'm using total 5 IR sensor and 1 color sensor. as IR_COLOR is the first IR sensor which is close to color sensor so I named it as IR_COLOR. So, that's not a big issue for me. I will name color sensor as something COLOR_Sen.

Comment: @jsotola Please, can you provide demo code related to flag for arduino? You may edit mine code too if you wish!

Comment: you are already using a flag variable in your code ... it is named `state`

Comment: YES! It's little confusing to me! can you please insert your logic of clearing flag by sensor in my code?

Comment: pick a value for `set` and a value for `clear` ... true/false ... HIGH/LOW ... 1/-1 ... 10/20 ... "abc"/"xyz" ... etc. etc. ... right now your code uses HIGH and LOW ... true/false is the most convenient because the `if` statements operate on true/false ... `if ( state ) {}` and  `if ( !state ){}`

Comment: use pen and paper... write description of the desired behavior in words ... something like `if sensor is LOW then clear the flag` ... a clear description translates to code almost directly

Comment: I have edited my code a bit and here's it! I don't understant arduino flags so I wanted you to edit my basic code with flags!  Here's my edited code link:    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ulzu5nnARIugKC4R7LD0-OWzkvYRSgdi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: there is no such thing as `arduino flags` ... this is C or C++ programming ... you are already using a flag variable in your code ... the flag name is `state` ... the value of the flag variable controls the motor `if (state == LOW) digitalWrite(Motor, LOW);`  ... I don't know if that turns the motor on or off ... I will not download anything from Google drive

Comment: @jsotola Indeed! But the problem lies with the timing! As, Object reaches ahead of IR sensor, the ESP32 turns off motor as mentioned in code but I want it to stay off for a few ms like 500ms and after 500ms it ESP32 should start the motor again even though IR sensor is detecting object! How can I translate this in code for arduino?

Comment: @jsotola I have edited the code in main post of mine! You may check that for reference!

Answer (score 2):

You have the general idea.

Your code looks a bit cluttered. Comments are not part of the program, keep them away from the code.

The `if` statements reduce to `if (true)`, that means that `== true` part is redundant.
All you need is `if(state)`. The `if` block will execute when `state` is true.
Conversely `if (!state)` tests for `state` being false

When there are only two possible values, then `else if(state == true)` can be simply `else`.

Identical code that is in both parts of the `if-else` block should be moved to outside of the block, `rememberTime=millis();` should be moved to after the closing brace `}` of the `if-else` block.

Here is some code that does what you want.

This code has not been tested on a hardware device.

https://wokwi.com/projects/364353854313747457

```cpp
const int     sensor_blocked  = LOW;              // define sensor values
const int     sensor_clear    = HIGH;

const int     motor_on        = HIGH;
const int     motor_off       = LOW;

const int     master_enable   =  2;
const int     motor_pin       =  3;
const int     sensor_pin      = 12;

int           sensor_state;
int           sensor_previous = sensor_clear;
int           motor_state     = motor_on;

unsigned long millis_previous = 0;
unsigned long millis_now;

const long    interval        = 500;  

void setup() {

  pinMode(master_enable, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(sensor_pin,    INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(motor_pin,     OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

  sensor_state = digitalRead( sensor_pin );

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  if ( sensor_state != sensor_previous ) {             // only run this code when sensor state changes
    sensor_previous = sensor_state;                    // remember new sensor state
    
    if ( sensor_state == sensor_blocked ) {            // sensor became blocked
      motor_state = motor_off;                         // turn off motor
      millis_previous = millis();                      // start of "motor off" interval
    }
    delay(20);                                         // debounce sensor
  }

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  if ( motor_state == motor_off ) {                    // timer check is relevant only when motor is off
    millis_now = millis();
    if ( millis_now - millis_previous >= interval ) {  // check if timer expired
      motor_state = motor_on;                          // enable motor
    }
  }

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  if ( digitalRead( master_enable ) != LOW ) motor_state = motor_off;     // master switch

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  digitalWrite(motor_pin, motor_state);                // translate motor state into action

}
```